# In Python, how to match a string in a word

Tags: python

Python code

```
str= "bcd"
word = "abcd1"

if pattern = re.search(str, word):
    print pattern.group(1)
```

I want to search "bdc" in a word.. how do I do it?

Comment: Don't use `str` as name for variables. If will mask (overwrite) `str()` a rather important built-in function of Python. It might have strange side effects.

Comment: You already wrote (or, more likely, copied from someone else) code that does exactly that. The one and only thing the code you're showing us does is the one thing you're asking us how to do. So what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> str= "bcd" 
>>> word = "abcd1"
>>> str in word
True
```

Simple way

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with find() function of a string object.

```
str = "abc"
word = "abcd1"

index = word.find (str)
if ( index != -1 ) :
    print (index)
```

Index shows the first character of the subsecuence that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word.index(str)`. It will return the position of `str` in `word`, or raise an exception if `str` is not found in `word`.

But if you like/want to use regular expressions, your use of `re.search()` is correct. `re.search` returns a match if the pattern is found in the string, or `None` if it is not found. Since `None` evaluates to `False`, you can just do:

```
if re.search(str, word):
    # found the pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is to know if string is contained in word, you can also simply:

```
if str in word:
   whatever
else:
   somethingelse
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether you need any information, like what position the result is in. If you just want a simple check, you can use the "If X in Y" approach:

```
In [1]: needle = "pie"

In [2]: haystack = "piece of string"

In [3]: if needle in haystack: print True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to know if the string is in another word, you can do:

```
if 'bdc' in word:
# do something
```

If you need to do that with regex:

```
import re
pat = re.compile('bdc')
pat.search(word)
```

(Or just `re.search('bdc', word)` )

Also, you should most likely never use `str` as an variable name, as it already is a builtin function `str()`

Comment: You don't have to do `re.compile` and then call the `search` method, you can just use `re.search`. In which case you have exactly the same code the OP started with, of course, which already works…

Comment: True, but in case you need to use that same pattern more often, it is more efficient to compile it

Comment: No it isn't, because the `re` module caches patterns. Unless maybe you have hundreds of patterns, and you know that a few of the earliest ones are going to be used repeatedly later while some of the later ones are only used once, so you need to manage the caching more explicitly. But at any rate, what's the point of trying to micro-optimize this in the first place?